# Как импортировать модуль из вложеной директории, импортирующий модуль из вложеной директории

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт, python-import

**Проблема:**

Не выходит запустить функцию импортируемую из вложенной директории,
которая использует переменную импортируемую из на уровень глубже вложенной директории.

**Дерево проекта:**

[image: дерево проекта:]

**Содержание файлов:**

[image: содержание файлов]

При запуске my_func() из main.py появляется ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\My project\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from functions.func import my_func
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\My project\functions\func.py", line 1, in <module>
    from variables.vars import my_var
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'variables'
```

Проблема не наблюдается если все три файла находятся на одном уровне вложенности.

Уважаемые знатоки!
Как правильно настроить импорты, чтобы `my_func()` можно было запускать из **main.py**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

**func.py**

```
# -> vvvvvvvvvv <----------------------------------------------------
from functions.variables.vars import my_var


def my_func():
    print(my_var)
```

Answer (score 1):

Импорт бывает [абсолютный и относительный](https://tonais.ru/osnovy/otnositelnyy-absolyutnyy-import-v-python).

Абсолютный импорт включает полный путь к вашему скрипту, начиная с корневой папки программы.

При относительном импорте указывается, где находятся ваши ресурсы относительно текущего файла кода.
Используется точечная нотация - относительный путь (начиная с пути текущего модуля) к желаемому модулю.
Формат from .<модуль/пакет> import X, где символы точки . показывают, на сколько директорий «вверх» нужно подняться. Одна точка . показывает текущую директорию, две точки .. — на одну директорию выше и т. д.

```
from .variables.vars import my_var
```

Comment: Единственный нюанс, что файл с таким импортом не получится запустить. Из него можно только импортировать